# Search multiple remote file systems at once?

Tags: files, remote

Say that I've lost a particular file. I know part of the name, so I could use something like this to find it:

```
sudo find / -iname "*filename*"
```

...except that I can't remember which device or server I left it on. It could be on any one of my external drives, or on servera.example.com, or serverb.example.com, or in one of GitHub repositories... you get the idea.

I could go searching every different place one by one, but that would take ages and I'm lazy.

Is there a way I search all my local devices and remote servers (and possibly my GitHub repositories too!) at once for a filename that I've lost?

Comment: On your machines: install `locate`, run `updatedb`, run `locate` to find the file.  Use something like [pssh](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Perl) to do it on all machines at once.  On your external drives: connect as many as you can at the same time, run `updatedb`, save the database.  Run `locate` when you indexed them all.  On GitHub: you can probably get away with a search.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Thanks for the advice. I was hoping for a (terminal based) tool that would do them all at once automatically for me, but I suppose this is the next best thing.

Comment: There's also the good, old `glimpse`, if you're willing to do the extra work.  There are, of course, ready-made "desktop search" solutions for KDE and the like.